# python iterating over list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I try to iterate over each item in the list. But iterator does not go through all objects.
Here is my function code(dirs and root comes from os.walk)

```
def remove_hidden_dirs(dirs,root):
    """
    Function remove hidden directories . .. in unix
    """
    logging.debug("\n\n remove hidden" )
    logging.debug('Start removing hidden dirs for %s',root)
    logging.debug("Length of dirs %s",len(dirs))
    logging.debug('File list before removing')
    dirs.sort()
    for d in dirs:
        logging.debug(d)
    i=0
    for d in dirs:
        i=i+1
        logging.debug("Iterating over %s",d)
        if d[0:1] == '.' or d[0:2] =='..':
            dirs.remove(d)
            logging.debug("Dir %s is being removed because of being hidden dir",d)
        else:
            logging.debug("Dir %s is NOT being removed because of being hidden dir",d)
    logging.debug("Iterate on %s", i)
    logging.debug('File list after removing')
    for d in dirs:
        logging.debug(d)
    logging.debug('end remove hidden files\n\n')
    return dirs
```

And here is part of my log.file

```
DEBUG:root:Start removing hidden dirs for /home/artur/
DEBUG:root:Length of dirs 38
DEBUG:root:File list before removing
DEBUG:root:.adobe
DEBUG:root:.android
DEBUG:root:.cache
DEBUG:root:.config
DEBUG:root:.dbus
...
DEBUG:root:Iterate on 22 dirs
DEBUG:root:File list after removing
DEBUG:root:.adobe
DEBUG:root:.cache
DEBUG:root:.dbus
...
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple: you are removing the current item from `dirs` while iterating over it. That means you skip two forward on the next loop. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list/6260097#6260097).

If what I said wasn't clear, say you iterate over this list of numbers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...]
 ^
```

That's the state of the list initially; then `1` is removed and the loop goes to the second item in the list:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6...]
    ^
```

Since you've removed `1` *and* moved forward by one in the list, now you're at `3`, not `2`.

```
[2, 4, 5, 6...]
```

Then you remove `3`... and so on.

Comment: A quick fix is to duplicate the list by slicing it: for d in dirs[:]

Comment: More importantly: this means the loop skips certain entries, because they've all shifted one place.

Comment: @Robin, that's what I said. Isn't it?

Comment: @senderle, the answer didn't say that when I commented, but now it does.

Comment: @Robin, I'll clarify: that's what I meant when I said "That means you skip two forward on the next loop," which _was_ in the very first version of my post.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Thanks Peter for sugestion it is worth to remember

Answer (score 9):

Don't modify lists while iterating over them. Instead, produce a new list with just the items that you want to keep.

```
dirs = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith('.')]
```

Is an efficient simple and readable technique for doing it.